# How to connect to external database through SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have a server, being hosted by an external hosting provider. To work on the server, I just need to remote connect with an IP address, a username, and password. When I remote connect, I can open SQL Server Management Studio and work on the databases. I use:

```
Server Name: (local)
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Username: SERVER\Administrator (Administrator is the username to remote connect)
```

I would like to connect to the server databases from SQL Server on my local machine. I obviously can't use `(local)` as the Server Name, and I can't use Windows Authentication.

I'm terrible with configuring things like this, and I really don't even know what to search for. Do I need to set up something in SQL Server on my server? Or can I use the credentials for the server to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to do this as the firewall will block the port that SQL Server communicates over.  The hosting provider probably won't allow this traffic over their firewall as it's a big security risk.

Essentially you're stuck with the remote desktop.

The other possibility is a VPN arrangement or SSH tunneling.  See if your provider can support an IPSEC VPN.  If you can set up a VPN then you should be able to connect to the server that way.

Comment: So there's no way to get the connection string for the databases at all, just to see if it is blocking the port?

Comment: @Steven - I promise you, the port is blocked. And if by some miracle it's not, you need to find a new host.

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be two issues.

1. The [ports will need to be open on the remote server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932) to connect from your machine to the server
2. When using Windows Authentication, there will need to be a trust relationship between SERVER and the authentication domain for the account running SSMS on the local machine

You can get around 2 by making a SQL Server account in the server (if you have rights to do that) and logging in as a SQL Server user instead of relying on a domain controller for authentication.

1 is not as easy to get around without some kind of VPN or other tunnel.  Once you set up a SQL Server user, just try to connect to the machine by IP address instead of (local).